# When installing Mint Linux in VMware player which OS version should I select?

Tags: linux, vmware, linux-mint

I just downloaded the iso for the 64bit version of [Mint Linux](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=132). I want to run it from Windows and to do this I installed the free version of VMware player. It said it couldn't auto detect the type of operating system and is asking me to specify. I choose Linux and it gave me the sub category to choose from a whole bunch of versions such as Debian, Ubuntu, "other" and the 64 bit versions of them. Which one should I select (Mint isn't on the list)?

[image: screen shot of different options to choose from in the new virtual machine wizard]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This box is used only to determine minimum hardware required to run given OS, best compatibility options and installation automation method.

Speaking of requirements and compatibility, Mint should work fine with Ubuntu presets. I'm not sure about setup automation, but you can give it a try. In case of setup failing take notes on what hardware Player had assigned for the Ubuntu preset, then create new VM but this time choosing *Other Linux 3.x kernel* and configure identical hardware. Installation automation will be skipped for *Other*.

Answer (score 2):

Mint is a spin-off of Ubuntu which is a spin-off of Debian.
So first preference is Ubuntu 64bit, then Debian 64bit.
As a last resort try "Other Linux" with the highest 64bit kernel available and then work you way downwards to earlier kernel presets if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which Mint version you downloaded. There is an Ubuntu-based Mint, and a Debian-based Mint edition called LMDE, based on Debian-testing. So I suggest you act on the basis of this knowledge. The fact that a Mint option does not exist is indicative of the fact that the choice is not truly critical, given its popularity. I have run in the past an Arch Linux VM off the generic choice Linux Kernel 3.x 64 bits without any problem.

Comment: In the question I provided the link to the site I downloaded Mint from. Is this the Debian or Ubuntu based version?

Comment: It is the Ubuntu-based version.